# Stanford sentiment - Cannot replicate same experiments with same accuracy - I get 79% instead of 85%

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-processing, sentiment-analysis

I am using the Stanford NLP for Sentiment Analysis,

but after training the model for more or less 24 hours, the session ended for maximum training time exceeded.

After running the evaluation of the created models, I have found out that the results in accuracy are far less performing than the ones from the Stanford paper.

> **These are the results of the Evaluation**:
>
> Tested 82600 labels
>
> 65166 correct
>
> 17434 incorrect
>
> 0.788935 accuracy
>
> Tested 2210 roots
>
> 828 correct
>
> 1382 incorrect
>
> 0,374661 accuracy
>
> Approximate Negative label accuracy: 0,595578
>
> Approximate Positive label accuracy: 0,663263
>
> Combined approximate label accuracy: 0,634001
>
> Approximate Negative root label accuracy: 0,665570
>
> Approximate Positive root label accuracy: 0,601760
>
> Combined approximate root label accuracy: 0,633718

I decided to retrain the model and set a MaximumTrainTimeSeconds to 3 days, hoping to get better accuracy performance.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Do you think that retraining the algorithm for a longer period would make me achieve the expected accuracy?

Moreover, I am not entirely sure of how the score described in the model (e.g. 79,30 in the model in the picture) relates to the accuracy-best performance of the model.

I'm very new to NLP so if I am missing any required information or anything at all please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper against which you are comparing these results.

Comment: Also, please explicitly state what data you are using to train the model. Is it the exact same data on which the benchmark has been trained?

Comment: The paper is http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf